# SVNDumpFilter include branches, too?

Tags: svn, svndumpfilter

I am trying to split out a repo that has multiple projects in it into stand-alone repos. Let's say I have the following structure, currently:

```
   /MyRepo
        /Trunk
            /Source
                /Project1
                    ...
                /ProjectN
        /Branches
            /Branch1
                /Source
                    /Project1
                        ...
                    /ProjectN
            /AnotherProject
                /Branch3 >> Note: nested branch
                    /Source
                        /Project1
```

So if I wanted to dump Project1, I want to get all related paths, that could be:

- /MyRepo/Trunk/Source/Project1/
- /MyRepo/Branches/Branch1/Source/Project1
- /MyRepo/Branches/AnotherProject/Branch3/Source/Project1

Basically I want to include all references to Project1 from Trunk and Branches, including nested branches.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In easy case you can `svndumpflter include` with a [set of paths in one command](http://blog.rlucas.net/uncategorized/some-gotchas-with-using-svndumpfilter/) (handwork)
- You can (?) also play with `--pattern` option (if instead of enumerating paths by substring you can build glob-pattern) - see Examples from [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svndumpfilter.commands.c.include.html) page

Comment: Thanks, it was not clear in the docs (maybe I missed it) that you could include multiple `PATH_PREFIX` arguments.